# IPTables: Firewall with just one Eth device?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

Admittedly I am a novice in the area of firewalls. But I have read on the IPtables and Firewall theory and command options. There is a general diagram by Rusty Russell, the creator of IPtables:

```
                      _____
INCOMING             /     \      OUTGOING
   -->[Routing ]--->|FORWARD|------->
      [Decision]     \_____/        ^
           |                        |
           v                       ____
          ___                     /    \
         /   \                  |OUTPUT|
        |INPUT|                  \____/
         \___/                      ^
           |                        |
            ----> Local Process ----
```

This diagram in its various form makes its way in all IPTables/Netfilter literature, books, etc.

My question, of a novice in this area, are:

a. I CLEARLY understand this diagram if INCOMING and OUTGOING refer to two different Ethernet ports (eth0 and eth1, for example). Is it possible to have the INCOMING and OUTGOING be the same Ethernet card(just eth0)? If so, can someone explain how.

b. Why is there no "Routing Decision" after the OUTPUT chain. I mean packets which originate from the host will also require some routing decisions. Right?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to use the following diagram http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.svg , http://l7-filter.sourceforge.net/PacketFlow.png , http://blog.frolov.at/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/packet_flow9.png

Comment: @ALex_hha Excellent! The best diagram on IPtables and I have seen many of them! Answers my second question. My first rather stupid question (already scorned for asking) but one for which I do not have a definite answer in my mind still persists: In theory, can a machine with just one Ethernet card be configured as a firewall? For the diagram alone, if you present this comment as an answer, I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have the INCOMING and OUTGOING be the same Ethernet card(just eth0)?

Yes: the simplest way to acheive this (there are other approaches but they get very messy) is to configure the card with [aliases and different subnets](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/set-up-ethernet-aliases-in-linux/).

> Why is there no "Routing Decision" after the OUTPUT chain

Because it's not necessary and that would potentially send the packet back into a different output chain (which might in turn send it back to the original output chain)